# setting PDF output name dynamically ion Rmarkdown

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

I am looking for a way to define the name of my rendered pdf from within the code.
I know I could render the 'md' but I would like to make this included in the Rmd instead so that I can render from within RStudio.
The name will be defined in the R code in some chunk and is not known in advance (therefore cannot be places in the YAML).

Is there a way like

> opts_chunk$set(render_output_name=)

??

Also setting the path where to save would be really cool

Thanks

Comment: You can do that in the function `rmarkdown::render()` and the argument `output_file = ...`. But I don't think you can do that when knitting your file via RStudio's knitting button.